# Apagar partes de um Texto

Tags: linux, shell

Galera é o seguinte queria conseguir extrair somente o nome do usuário em um SCRIPT Shell porém tem que ser obrigatoriamente através do texto que eu informar.

Eu queria exatamente exibir na tela somente: meucliente
Do texto: /home/meucliente/publlic_html

Isso é para um script de backup personalizado que eu estou montando, basicamente quero apagar sempre o texto /home/ e o texto /public_html de qualquer texto que eu informar, porém estou apanhando pra conseguir.

Answer (score 2):

Manipulação de Strings (Bash):

```
#!/bin/bash
txt='/home/meucliente/public_html'
aux=${txt%/*}
aux=${aux##*/}
echo $aux
```

Expressões Regulares (Bash):

```
#!/bin/bash
txt='/home/meucliente/public_html'
[[ $txt =~ /([^/]+)/[^/]*$ ]]
echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

Usando o `awk`:

```
#!/bin/bash
txt='/home/meucliente/public_html'
awk -F "/" '{ print $3 }' <<< $txt
```

Usando o `sed`:

```
#!/bin/bash
txt='/home/meucliente/public_html'
sed 's,/[^/]\+/\([^/]\+\)/.*,\1,' <<< $txt
```

Usando o `cut`:

```
#!/bin/bash
txt='/home/meucliente/public_html'
cut -d/ -f3 <<< $txt
```

Bash String Split Array:

```
#!/bin/bash
txt='/home/meucliente/public_html'
IFS='/' arr=( $txt )
echo "${arr[2]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Pode fazer desta forma:

```
#!/bin/bash
caminho='/home/meucliente/publlic_html'

from="/home/"
replace=""
caminho=${caminho//$from/$replace}

from="/publlic_html"
replace=""
caminho=${caminho//$from/$replace}

echo $caminho
```

Comment: Minha opção natural ia ser jogar para o `sed`, mas tratar como expansão de variável é muito mais leve

Answer (score 1):

Você pode o fazer com `cut`:

```
echo "/home/meucliente/public_html" | cut -d'/' -f3
```

Comment: Pelo que entendi, `meucliente` é uma informação desejada. Seu `cut` não removeria isso?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Não, somente removeria as cadeias da primeira e terça posição, nesse caso: `/home/` e `/public_html`. O `cut -d'/' -f3` fica só com a parte após a segunda barra

Comment: Verdade, esqueci da barra inicial